# How to Listen additional port to receive data in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

How to listen to some additional port to receive data from external service and print the received data whenever the external service sends data…how can I do it in Meteor.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need another port, or just an endpoint? You can define additional endpoints to receive data without needing a UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor apps are Node apps, so you can use the modules from the NodeJS API

For TCP or IPC use net.Server [`net.createServer()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createserver_options_connectionlistener)

For UDP use dgram [`dgram.createSocket('udp4');`](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_udp_datagram_sockets)